# Paste not returning files side by side?

Tags: bash, shell

File that I already have (list1.txt):

```
test
for
you
```

File that I make

```
list2='test2\nfor2\nyou2'
echo $list2 > list2.txt
```

Now when I try to do `paste list1.txt list2.txt`, it just returns

```
test test2 for for2 you you2
```

I'm aiming for it to return

```
test   test2
for    for2
you    you2
```

It's like it treats \n as spaces, please help.

Comment: *Now when I try to do* `paste list1.txt list2.txt`... How do you do it? My impression is that you use it in an unquoted command substitution, e.g. `echo $(paste listt1.txt list2.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `echo` to interpret escape sequences ie do

```
echo -e "$list2" > list2.txt
```

Then, for a nice formatted output you could do something like

```
paste list1.txt list2.txt | expand -t 15
```

The `expand` manual says :

> -t, --tabs=LIST
>                 use comma separated list of explicit tab positions

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
 echo -e $list2 > list2.txt
```

man echo

```
- e
 Enable interpretation of the following backslash-escaped
 characters in each STRING:

\a          alert (bell)

\b          backspace

\c          suppress trailing newline

\e          escape 

\f          form feed

\n          new line

\r          carriage return

\t          horizontal tab

\v          vertical tab

\\          backslash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# Use $'...' notation to expand backslash-escaped characters
list2=$'test2\nfor2\nyou2'
echo "$list2"
test2
for2
you2

# make sure to use quoted variable
$> echo "$list2" > list2.txt

$> paste list1.txt list2.txt

test    test2
for     for2
you     you2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `list2.txt` file:

```
$ cat list2.txt
test2\nfor2\nyou2
```

The `echo` command does not interpret `\n` as a newline. For that, you need to either use `-e` with `echo` (nonportable) or use `printf` (portable):

```
$ printf "test2\nfor2\nyou2\n" >list2.txt
```